# initialize array that is within a object, use in localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, javascript-objects

**Isolated Question:**

```
user[username] = { 
  cool: true,
  stuff: false,
  arrData: []
};
```

I am trying to globally initialize my arrData array in order to populate in different scope; the below does not work.

```
let user.arrData = [],
```

later I want to do the following, for context:

```
...........
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
      user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(username)); // tried moving this here
      user.arrData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
      // the above errors on .arrData cannot push undefined, I have tried also including the key here, how is this done?
  });
  localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(user.arrData));
  console.log({ arrData: user.arrData }); // returns undefined
............
```

**Sub question:** can I set and retrieve a object.array with `localStorage` like this. Meaning my reference to `(user.arrData)`?

---

Context/actual code:

**Below is the complete relevant code for context: I am trying to save a series of checkbox states per user with local storage, then reload them when a button is clicked.**

```
let user = {};
var savebtnBM = document.getElementById("savebtnBM");
const username = document.querySelector("span.name").textContent;

user[username] = { 
   cool: true,
   stuff: false,
   arrData: []
};

var layersMod =  document.querySelectorAll(".layers #savebtnBM")[0];
layersMod.addEventListener('click', ()=>{ 
setTimeout(
  function() {
    Saver();
  }, 2000);
});

function Saver() { 
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  // var arrData = [];
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    user[username].arrData.push({ id: input.id, checked: input.checked });
  });
  localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(user.arrData));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user.arrData));
}

var etHOME= document.getElementById("et-phone-home");
etHOME.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(username));
    console.log(user);
    document.getElementsByClassName("big-button")[0].click();
    setTimeout(load_, 2000);

    function load_() {
      var inputs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(user));
      inputs.forEach(function(input){
        document.getElementById(input.id).checked = input.checked;
        load__();
      });
    function load__() { 
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
        for(var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
          elems[i].click();
        }
      }
    } 
});
```

Comment: What do you want the result `let userA.arrData = []` to be? `arrData` is already initialized to `[]` when you define `user[key]`.

Comment: Console says it is not defined; arrData, it works and populates when I take it out of user object and initialize by itself with var arrData = [] - so it must be something with it being user object.

Comment: What is the functionality of`let userA.arrData = []` ? 
Maybe you need to `user[key].arrData = [];`

Comment: @LeandroMatilla and @ igg I have added the full relevant code for context and revised the OP.

Comment: @CaptainRon There seem to be syntax errors. First you define `user`, then you try to access `userA`. Also, you rely on the result of `document.querySelector` to get a key for `user[username]`, which is dangerous. For starters, replace every instance of `userA` with `user` and see what happens.

Comment: This was just a typo in the post; they are consistent. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: i.e.   localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log({ arrData: user.arrData }); -- currently is returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

**Sub question response:**

---

The `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` can only handle strings.

So first we must convert our object to string with `JSON.stringify()` as in the following example:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

When it comes to obtaining the previously saved we do the opposite, using `JSON.parse()`:

```
//...
const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log({ arrData: storedUser.arrData });
```

Comment: Thanks but; localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(user)); console.log({ arrData: user.arrData }); -- currently is returning undefined in my above code.